# Can a directed graph be split into two groups such that nodes don't connect to each other within groups?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

I'm looking for an algorithm that checks that for the given **directed graph** its nodes can be split into two groups such that nodes don't connect to each other **within their group**

For example

[image]
[image]

**UPD**

I need to check on Bipartite graphs, that's it

Comment: I think you're looking for a [bipartite graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph).

Comment: @beaker thanks, you're right!

Comment: Regarding your second example. What about the split {1,2} and {0,3}?

Comment: @RafałDowgird yeah, correct. I should've added more connections to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph you are describing is called a [Bipartite Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bipartite_graph).

[image]

[This](https://cp-algorithms.com/graph/bipartite-check.html) is a way to check if a given graph is Bipartite or not.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I need indeed.